# Excel: Min/Max sum amount per person within unique dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel table with 3 columns (please see picture attached below): **Date**, **Name (Initials)** and **Amount Spent**

I'd like to return the value of the minimum and maximum summed amounts (separately) spent for each person per date (B31:C33).

I thought of a formula looking like so:

`{=MIN(SUMIFS(C2:C26,B2:B26=A31, A2:A26))}`

Or like so:

`{=SUMPRODUCT(--(C2:C26,B2:B26=A31,?))}`

[image: [Excel Image Sample]

Unfortunately, I am unable to return the correct value. I would be grateful to receive your help.

I'll be looking forward to some responses.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a good first post, I'll be happy to write up an answer for this question at the end of my working day in 35 minutes if it hasn't already been answered by then.

Comment: Thank you @Glitch_Doctor. Looking forward to it!

Comment: Still trying, though I think I'm getting closer with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idccys7QR7M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, sorry for the delay answering this. I had a rather urgent flurry of bug fixes to attend to at work.

***This is an array formula, array formulas must be confirmed by pressing*** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

MIN - 
`=SMALL(IF(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$26,$A$2:$A$26,IF($B$2:$B$26=$A30,$A$2:$A$26),$B$2:$B$26,$A30),SUMIFS($C$2:$C$26,$A$2:$A$26,IF($B$2:$B$26=$A30,$A$2:$A$26),$B$2:$B$26,$A30)),1)`

MAX - `=LARGE(IF(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$26,$A$2:$A$26,IF($B$2:$B$26=$A30,$A$2:$A$26),$B$2:$B$26,$A30),SUMIFS($C$2:$C$26,$A$2:$A$26,IF($B$2:$B$26=$A30,$A$2:$A$26),$B$2:$B$26,$A30)),1)`

It looks fairly big so let's talk you through it:

You may have noticed that the only thing that has changed in this formula is `SMALL()` to `LARGE()`, this is because the `SUMIFS()` array is handling the total for each day for that "Person Initials".

`SUMIFS([amounts to sum],[dates],`

We break off here to produce an array of dates for criteria 1 of `SUMIFS()`:

`IF([name initials]=[person initials],[dates])`

As this is an array, we end up with a list of matching dates or `FALSE` like so: `{43252;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;43301;43301;FALSE;43301;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;43342;43342;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;43317;43317;43317}`

That's the first criteria nailed and the second criteria is simply the "Name (Initials)"

`,[name initials],[person initials])`

What we now have though, is an array of 0 for where the criteria has not matched and the amounts that we would like to assess.

To make the data useful to us, we make use of the binary nature of Excel in that a 0 will be read as a `FALSE` result for an `IF()` statement:

`IF([result from formula],[result from formula])`

This translates the `SUMIFS()` result back to either `FALSE` or our totals.

We are now free to use `MIN([formula])` or `SMALL([formula],1)` to get our smallest value.

As 0 will not be returned fro the maximum providing you have any matched values, you don't need to actually perform the binary trick for `MAX([formula])` or `LARGE([formula],1)`:

`=MAX(IF(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$26,$A$2:$A$26,IF($B$2:$B$26=$A30,$A$2:$A$26),$B$2:$B$26,$A30))`

Again, sorry for the delay and I appreciate that it's a lot to take in so feel free to ask any questions.

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Glitch_Doctor, that works fantastick. Sorry I hadn't replied before. I've had to shift over to Google Sheets (wrapping the formula with `ARRAYFORMULA` and unfortunately the formula doesn't work there. When trying with `SMALL(`, it returns **SMALL has no valid input data** and when using `MIN(` it returns a **0**. I really don't understand what this means. Please, are you able to tell what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be answered with a PivotTable:

> **Assuming you want the absolute minimum and the absolute maximum for all the dates**

- In 'Rows' you add the initials, since you will want a minimum and a maximum *by person*, throughout all the dates.
- In 'Values' you want the Amount Spent, but not the *Sum* (which is the default value shown)... You can change the Values so that one shows the *Min*, and the other shows the *Max*.

***Follow the following steps:***

**Start**
You should start by selecting your table (A1:C26) and then go to `Insert... PivotTable`. I created a dummy spreadsheet with only a few values, so in my case I selected (A1:C10):

[image: Start]
**Step 1**
After you create your PivotTable, it will be empty. Click on the large icon that appears and a menu with PivotTable Fields will appear on the right. Here, drag Name (Initials) to Rows and Amount Spent to Values, twice. It will then look like this:

[image: Step1]

**Step 2**
The PivotTable is showing the sum of the amounts, but you want the minimum and maximum. These can be changed by clicking on the info button to the right and then selecting your intended calculation (e.g. minimum):

[image: Step2]

**Step 3**
Repeat Step 2 and change to the maximum.

**End Result**
The end result will be this:
[image: EndResult]

I removed the Grand Totals, since they were meaningless, in `Design... Grand Totals... Off for rows and columns`. This menu appears only if you click the PivotTable.

> **Assuming you want to do this for each date**

Easy! On top of what you already did, just drag Date to the Columns and it will show one minimum and one maximum per unique date.

[EDIT] Getting the Date to the Columns doesn't answer the question, but based on the comment, what if you add it to Rows? You will get something like this:

[image: newtry]

Which can be summarised into a table like this, which seems to be what you want:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @AVLZ. It's good to get my head around pivot tables as I've never done so, but unfortunately this method doesn't return the correct values. Even by adding the date in the column section.

What it returns:
The minimum value out of each individual cells, sorted by names.

What I'd like it to return:
I'd like to capture (in an array) the sum spent per day for each person, then return the minimum value in one column and maximum value in another.

Comment: I edited the last part of my answer to see if it solves the problem, I think I hadn't understood what you wanted :) is that it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I'd need each days to be summed up per person, then to display the unique minimum/maximum across all dates for a single person. The edited solution only shows individual values instead of sums per day per person.